# Rails - get polymorphic children from collection as ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, children, polymorphic-associations, pg-search

I need to get all children from a parent as an ActiveRecord::Relation. Thing is, this children are stored in a polymorphic relation. In my case I need it to paginate some search results obtained with `pg_search` gem.

I've tried the following:

```
results = PgSearch.multisearch('query').map(&:searchable)
# Horrible solution, N + 1 and returns an array

docs = PgSearch.multisearch('query').includes(:searchable)
results = docs.map(&:searchable)
# Still getting an array
```

Also thought of things like select or pluck, but they are not intended for retrieving objects, only column data. I could try to search ids for each children type like so

```
Post.where(id: PgSearch.multisearch('query').where(searchable_type: "Post").select(:searchable_id)
Profile.where(id: PgSearch.multisearch('query').where(searchable_type: "Profile").select(:searchable_id)
```

But it doesn't scale, since I would need to do this for every object I want to obtain from a search result.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here's some basic pseudocode demonstrating the issue:
    class Profile < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :search_document, :as => :searchable
    end

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :search_document, :as => :searchable
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :search_document, :as => :searchable
end

class SearchDocument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :searchable, plymorphic: true
end
```

I want to obtain all the searchable items as an ActiveRecord::Relation, so that I can dynamically filter them, in this specific case, using `limit(x).offset(y)`

```
SearchDocument.all.joins(:searchable).limit(10).offset(10)
```

Generates an error: cannot eagerly load searchable cause of polymorphic relation

```
SearchDocument.all.includes(:searchable).limit(10).offset(10)
```

This one does load the searchable items into memory, but does not return them in the query, instead it applies the filters to the `SearchDocument` items, as expected. This might be a temporary solution, to filter the search documents and then get the searchable items from them, but collides with pagination on the views.

The question here is: Is there a way I can get all searchable items as ActiveRecord::Relation to further filter them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with this library. However, looking at your code, I'd guess that any attempt to take a CollectionProxy and map some function over it will trigger evaluating the CollectionProxy and return an array.

Having had a quick look at the library GitHub docs, perhaps something like this might work:

```
post_docs = PgSearch.multisearch('query').where(searchable_type: "Post")
posts = Post.where(pg_search_document: post_docs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a workable option,  and pretty aimilar to the last examples I gave. I guess it makes sense that mapping some function to the collection will return an array. Sadly for my case, I lose too many advantages by splitting the results by their type and doing `Post.where(pg_search_document: post_docs)`, it won't scale, I lose the order by ranking, etc. Is there no way to get this collection straight from the query?

Comment: Do these objects (posts, profiles, etc) share some common interface that isn't just part of the PgSearch::Document class? I'm trying to see how you plan on using the relation; perhaps you could give us a couple of lines of  pseudo code to show us what you'd like to do with this ActiveRecord::Relation?

Comment: I'm also struggling to see what you're trying to achieve that depends on being a relation, not an array, but isn't answered by `PgSearch.multisearch('query').includes(:searchable)`

Comment: I basically want to be able to dynamically filter the results from the query. In this specific case, I want to paginate the results by using `paginate(page: params[:page])` which does the same as `limit(x).offset(y)`. I've been reading and this problem is not specific for pg_search, but for polymorphic associations in general. I'll try adding some basic code that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: @AlejandroAristizábal Sure, but if you’re taking a page of data and displaying it, what fields are you displaying to the user? Do profiles and posts have some common data (ranks?)? Is this data part of the profile (say) or the pg_doc?

Comment: Ranks is something from the `pg_search` gem, you can ignore it. I just added some pseudocode on the answer. Thank you for being attentive